# Parse saltstack highstate output

Tags: python, parsing, salt-stack

I took the path python.
Now, I need parse output data saltstack
for example:

```
{"fun_args": [], "jid": "20180127110016597705", "return": {"biosversion": "0407\\nInvalid entry length (16). Fixed up to 11.", "kernel": "Linux", "domain": "corp.test.com", "uid": 0, "zmqversion": "4.1.4", "kernelrelease": "4.10.0-42-generic", "pythonpath": ["/usr/bin", "/usr/lib/python2.7", "/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu", "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk", "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old", "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload", "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages", "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages", "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0"], "serialnumber": "System Serial Number\\nInvalid entry length (16). Fixed up to 11.", "pid": 29227, "ip_interfaces": {"lo": ["127.0.0.1", "::1"], "enp6s0": ["10.0.1.83", "fe80::758:bc44:76a7:9bd6"]}, "groupname": "root", "fqdn_ip6": [], "mem_total": 3861,
```

Now I have this data as tuple with one element.
I can convert tuple to dict, but it has one element too.

I want parse this data, like this (dictionary):

```
{"fun_args": [], "jid": "20180127110016597705", 
"return": 
    {
    "biosversion": "0407\\nInvalid entry length (16). Fixed up to 11.", 
    "kernel": "Linux", 
    "domain": "corp.test.com", 
    "uid": 0, 
    "zmqversion": "4.1.4", 
    "kernelrelease": "4.10.0-42-generic", 
    "pythonpath": ["/usr/bin", "/usr/lib/python2.7", "/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu", "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk", "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old", "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload", "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages", "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages", "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0"], 
    "serialnumber": "System Serial Number\\nInvalid entry length (16). Fixed up to 11.", 
    "pid": 29227, 
    "ip_interfaces": {
                    "lo": ["127.0.0.1", "::1"], 
                    "enp6s0": ["10.0.1.83", "fe80::758:bc44:76a7:9bd6"]
                    }, 
    "groupname": "root", 
    "fqdn_ip6": [], 
    "mem_total": 3861,
```

Thanx.
I try that:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python

import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error

def connect():
    """ Connect to MySQL database """
    try:
        conn = mysql.connector.connect(host='10.0.0.125',
                                       database='salt',
                                       user='salt',
                                       password='salt')
        if conn.is_connected():
            #print('Connected to MySQL database')
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute("SELECT full_ret FROM salt_returns WHERE fun='grains.items'")

            row = cursor.fetchone()

            s = ''.join((row[0]))
            #print(s.split())
            list = s.split()
            #print(list)
            for i in list:
                print(i)

    except Error as e:
        print(e)

    finally:
        conn.close()
```

Comment: Show your code/effort please?

Comment: Not in comment section, edit it into the question.

Comment: Use Ctrl+K to format code.

Comment: If your data is in string and you want to construct a dict from it, use json.

Comment: sorry my syntax, its my first expirience for asking...

Comment: And what's the problem with the code? / You're new doesn't mean you can't read the SE formatting tutorials and how-to-ask pages.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I went to read.

Comment: Thanks very much. Json is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import mysql.connector
import json
from mysql.connector import Error


def connect():
    """ Connect to MySQL database """
    try:
        conn = mysql.connector.connect(host='10.0.0.125',
                                       database='salt',
                                       user='salt',
                                       password='salt')
        if conn.is_connected():
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute("SELECT full_ret FROM salt_returns WHERE fun='grains.items'")
            row = cursor.fetchone()

            s = ''.join((row))
            obj = json.loads(s)

            s2 = obj['return']
            for i in s2:
                print(i, s2[i])
                if type(s2[i]) is dict:
                    for i2 in s2[i]:
                        print(i2, s2[i][i2])
                elif type(s2[i]) is list:
                    for i3 in s2[i]:
                        print(i3)
    except Error as e:
        print(e)

    finally:
        conn.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    connect()
```